# Json callback handling in comment script

Tags: jquery, json

Below is the script for a comment form, which post with ajax to the database backend. 
there is a callback to show the comment in real-time (without page-refresh).

The callback handling is triggered by a json -string function (part of insert.php)

echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'html'=>$insertedComment->markup()));

However the javascript does not respond to it. What is wrong here?

```
    /* Listening for the submit event of the form: */
    $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();


        /* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */
        $.post('/comments/insert.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){



            if(msg.status){


                $('#body').val('');
            }
            else {

                /*
                /   If there were errors, loop through the
                /   msg.errors object and display them on the page
                /*/


            }
        },'json');

    });
```

Comment: Is something on the console?

Comment: You should probably begin by analyzing the response in your browsers' dev tools. If you provide a live example, I will be happy to take a look.